# IR plugin for gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, sensor, ir

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Would I know whether there is IR plugin for gazebo? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11983/ir-plugin-for-gazebo/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/2239/gazebo-irsensor-parameters-configuration-xml) question. It seems to provide some assistance in generating an IR sensor in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0